# Homogeneous metric on a homogeneous space $G/K$ - is this the same as a $G$ - invariant metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, group-actions

I have trouble putting down the notion of a homogeneous Riemannian metric.

Suppose we are given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ on which a compact Lie group $G$ acts transitively by isometries (this means that $h^*g = g$ for any $h \in G$, i.e. for any vector fields $X,Y$ on $M$ and any point $p \in M$,
$$
g_{h \cdot p} \big(h_{*,p}(X_p),h_{*,p}(Y_p)\big) = g_p\big(X_p,Y_p) \,.
$$
It also means that if we fix any point $p \in M$ and denote by $K$ the isotropy subgroup associated with $p$ then there is a smooth bijection $\varphi \colon G / K \to M$ given by $\varphi(hK) =  h \cdot p$.

Ok, this map then allows us to endow $G / K$ with a metric $\tilde g$ as follows: we decompose the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$ into $\mathfrak m \oplus \mathfrak k$ where $\mathfrak k$ is the Lie subalgebra of $K$ in $\mathfrak g$. Then we have an identification $T_pM \cong \mathfrak m \cong T_K(G/K)$, which allows us to set the value of $\tilde g$ at the point $hK$ on vector fields $X,Y$ over $G/K$ by
$$
 \tilde g_{hK}\big((L_{hK})_{*}(X_{K}),(L_{hK})_{*}(Y_{K})\big) := g_{p}\big(X_{K},Y_{K}\big)
$$
where $L_{hK}$ denotes left translation in $G / K$ by $hK$ and we use the isomorphism $T_pM \cong \mathfrak m \cong T_K(G/K)$  to identify $X_K$ and $Y_K$ with elements in $T_pM$. This metric is manifestly invariant under left translation by $G$ (simply because the right hand side does not see the effect of left translation), i.e. $\tilde g$ is a $G$ - invariant metric on $G / K$.

Is this also called a homogeneous metric? I know what homogeneous Riemannian manifolds are, these are precisely of the form given above, where a Lie group acts transitively by isometries, however when it comes to the notion of a homogeneous metric I would have to \emph{guess} that by this is meant the construction above .. is it correct? In other words, do we mean then that $(G/K,\tilde g)$ is a homogeneous Riemannian manifold? Thanks a lot for your feedback and help!!

Comment: Wouldn't you say that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism, and that the metric on the quotient $G/K$ is just the pullback $\tilde{g}=\varphi^*g$?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I think that's right (apologies if the above description is clumsy, I still need a lot of practice!)

Comment: Short answer:  a homogeneous Riemannian manifold is any Riemannian manifold whose isometry group acts transitively on the manifold.  Every such manifold is isometric to one of the form $(G/K,\tilde{g})$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks for your comment! Would you then also say that $\tilde g$ is a homogeneous metric? Or does the notion "homogeneous metric" mean something else ?

Comment: I would use the term "homogeneous metric" to mean "a metric for which the isometry group acts transitively".  So, yes, $\tilde{g}$ is a homogeneous metric according to this usage.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Ok I understand, thanks again!